# How to transpose concatenated values in columns to rows

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, apache-spark-sql

Input:

```
item   number
ABC     123
```

I want to output like this:

```
item   number
 A       1
 B       2
 C       3
```

Comment: question is unclear. what is ABC 123? are this part of one column or two? what have you tried so far?

Comment: are you attempting to perform this transformation in pure SQL?  HiveQL?  Spark?  PySpark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your you strings using `split()`, explode using `posexplode()` and use lateral view.
Split by empty string `''` will generate arrays with extra empty elements, filter them out, connect items and numbers by their positions in array.

**Demo (replace s subquery with your table):**

```
select i.itm as item, n.nbr as number
from
(--replace this subquery with your table
 --this is two rows example
select stack(2,'ABC', '123',
               'DEF', '456') as (item, number)   
) s --your_table  
lateral view posexplode(split(s.item,'')) i as pos, itm 
lateral view posexplode(split(s.number,'')) n as pos, nbr 
where i.itm!='' and n.nbr!='' and i.pos=n.pos ;
```

**Result:**

```
OK
item    number
A       1
B       2
C       3
D       4
E       5
F       6
Time taken: 0.094 seconds, Fetched: 6 row(s)
hive>
```

Update: simplified version

```
select i.itm as item, substr(s.number,i.pos+1,1) as number
from
(--replace this subquery with your table
 --this is two rows example
select stack(2,'ABC', '123',
               'DEF', '456') as (item, number)   
) s --your_table  
lateral view posexplode(split(s.item,'')) i as pos, itm 
where i.itm!='';
```